# From localhost to portforwarding with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, local

I have a question about my local environment. I can acces the shop trough dev.domain.com (but its 127.0.0.1) but then with edit in .hosts file.

Is it possible to port forward my 80 port and then acces my shop trough my home ip adres?

Do I need to change hostname in my database? Can someone put me in the right direction?